# Summing up the first k elements in a row of pascal's triangle.

Tags: combinatorics

I trying to come up with a formula for the number of functions there are that map n boolean variables to a boolean output supposing that the functions are a series of disjunctions of conjunctions with $k$ or less terms.

So, part of my answer involves determining how many conjunctions can be formed with $k$ or less terms over $n$ variables. I believe this is equal to $ \binom {n} {k}+ \binom {n}   {k- 1}+ \dots +\binom{n}  {k-k} $. However, I'm not very good with proofs in general and this recursion seems difficult to simplify. So I'm wondering whether there already a formula for summing the first $k$ rows of pascals triangle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what disjunctions or conjunctions are.

But the sum of row $k$ in Pascal triangle is $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j} = 2^k$ (counting the first row as $0$).

So the sum of the first $n$ rows is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k=2^n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for a sum of the elements in a row, not rows themselves.

Comment: It is right there, the second line.